# Is there a limit for transaction size?

Tags: transactions, gas, fees, blocks, gas-limit

Is there a theoretical limit for transaction data size when you send a transaction to Ethereum network?

Ref.

[Is there a (theoretical) limit for amount of data that a contract can store?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/is-there-a-theoretical-limit-for-amount-of-data-that-a-contract-can-store)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Wow this is such an interesting question! **TL;DR**: the transaction size limit, at the time of writing, is about **780kB** (about 3 million gas). But read on.

---

There is **no direct or fixed limit**, neither for transaction sizes nor for block sizes. This is a strength of the Ethereum network, it does scale.

That does not mean that there are no limits. There is the [block gas limit](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1092/87) of currently 3,141,592 gas which can be spent maximum per block.

That means, in theory, you could create a single transaction which consumes all the gas of a single block.

Let's try to send 256kB random data with a contract:

[image: trx with 256kb random data]

That would consume almost 9 million gas, which is not available currently. Mist tries to create the transaction but it will be invalid.

Let's try to create something close to the gas limit, *44,444 random bytes*:

[image: 44k random bytes]

That transaction went through, here is an [explorer link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x25e54394ab4e5f17d6e1240c02c1a6c4bb675ef9471f1105b006988f5fe5aec1). Hash:

```
I0207 11:47:14.558908 eth/api.go:946] Tx(0x25e54394ab4e5f17d6e1240c02c1a6c4bb675ef9471f1105b006988f5fe5aec1) to: 0xfcae7970392f510a985a7eaccd3820b7759d65d9
```

- Value:    60 Finney (0.06 Ether)
- Gas:  3131800
- Gas Price:    50 Gwei (0.00000005 Ether)
- Gas Used By Transaction:  3031800
- Actual Transaction Cost:  151.59 Finney (0.15159 Ether)
- Cumulative Gas Used:  3031800

So, I just added 44kB to the blockchain in block [967163](https://etherscan.io/block/967163).

And now, the scaling magic of Ethereum starts to kick in. In block [967164](https://etherscan.io/block/967164), the network reacts to the high gas consumption and **increases the block gas limit to 3,142,967**!

[image: gas limit increased]

So, if there is a continuous request in high gas consumption, the gas limit can be increased by plus/minus `1/1024`, which is around `0.09%`. See [yellow paper equations 40-42](https://gavwood.com/paper.pdf).

In short, limit: yes, at the time of writing about 780kB for a tx full of zero bytes, or 46kB for a tx full of non-zero bytes. Fixed limits (like in Bitcoin): no.

Comment: Update: in Homestead, the block gasLimit is now 4,712,388 (1.5 times PI million) and gas price is 20 GWei.  (Methodology above can still be used.)

Comment: I may have missed this, but how does 89kB == 3 million gas?

Comment: Uhm, it's not. Well spotted. It's probably around 40kB. Someone please redo the math, 3 million gas is also outdated. :-)

Comment: You was actually sending 44,444 random bytes. Because you had 178 zero bytes inside, intrinsic gas was 21,000 + (178 * 4) + (44,266 * 68) = 3,031,800. Gas limit is variable (now for example is 500k because of the recent attack to the network) so I think it is not worth to update that value in the answer.

Comment: With this last answer, I'm a bit confused. Is the gasLimit still equal to 3 141 388 gas , or is updated to 4,712,388? Thanks

Comment: It differs. currently around 4,000,000. check https://ethstats.net/ for details.

Comment: Since [this commit](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/eebde1a2e202e92eee722ff0841cda4bd0257a62) release with geth v1.6.6 will drop transactions over 32kb.

Answer (score 17):

As of **12/08/2017**, the gas limit as detailed on [EthStats.net](https://ethstats.net) is **6,700,314**.

The gas limit was 'stuck' at 4.7 million. It was [recommended](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6ehp60/recommendations_to_miners_to_change_gas_limit_and/) that miners change their settings such that the gas limit could be raised.

As outlined in [this article](https://www.coindesk.com/miners-ethereum-transactions-gas-limit/), this happened.

Each hexadecimal character is 4 bits. 2 characters is a byte.

The yellow paper outlines the fees for various operations.

[image: Yellow Paper Fees]

Using similar calculations to those used by 5hcdn/Giuseppe Bertone we can now see that a transaction could (in principle) hold ****

(6,700,314 - 21,000) / 68 = **98,225** (rounded down) non-zero bytes.

[image: EthGasStation stats]

Now.. the data provided by [EthGasStation](http://ethgasstation.info/) allows us to see that we could have a transaction mined with a gas price as low as 0.5 Gwei.

```
6,700,314 * 0.5 = 3,350,157 Gwei = 0.003350157 Ether.
```

A more standard 20 Gwei gas price would yield:

```
6,700,314 * 20 = 40,201,884 Gwei = 0.040201884 Ether.
```

At a current ETH price of around **$315** it would cost between **$1.05 and $12.66** to submit that much data to the block chain.

Comment: "As of 12/08/2017" 
Are you from the future?

Comment: Nope. I am British ;)