# Is it possible to verify Ethash PoW in a contract?

Tags: contract-design, proof-of-work, sha3, ethash

Reading on EtHash, I was thinking if it is possible to verify the current Ethereum Proof Of Work by a smart contract. There is an instruction SHA3, which computes 256-bit hash, but EtHash uses 512-bit hash. Was this discrepancy intentional or just an oversight? Is it possible to compute one from another somehow?

I know that verifying PoW in the contract might be expensive, but it could be used just as a response to a challenge.

Answer (score 3):

It seems impossible to do so, because [Ethash](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash) requires a 16 MB pseudorandom cache. This would be expensive to store on the blockchain, as each Ethereum transaction only holds a maximum of [89kB (3 million gas)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/is-there-a-limit-for-transaction-size).

Comment: The cache wouldn't need to be stored in the blockchain; it could be constructed (expensively) in instance memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is difficult because the time of doing RAM(Random Access Memory) accounts for the most part of Ethash.

Comment: You think?  Do you have any statistics or evidence to back this up?

Answer (score 0):

you can add new opcode in EVM to implement this function，but i have a problem in how to compile correctly in solidity. i will appreciate it if you show your method to prove your ethash's nonce in contract.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422805/how-verifies-the-nonce-produced-by-ethash-through-contract-add-new-opcode-in