# How to move DAO tokens in myetherwallet.com to Ethereum Wallet?

Tags: mist, wallets, tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet

I'm new to Ethereum and trying to learn. I bought DAO tokens using myetherwallet.com, I can see them when I log in, but how do I move them to Ethereum Wallet in order to Watch the Contract and Vote?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`@tayvano`'s answer will help you move your Ethereum accounts into Ethereum Wallet (Mist). You will have two more steps to do if you want to view your TheDAO tokens in the Ethereum Wallet and vote on proposals when the creation period ends.

## Viewing the DAO token in the Ethereum Wallet

Follow the steps on [daohub.org - Monitoring your balance](https://daohub.org/voting.html) to add the DAO token to Ethereum Wallet. In summary these steps are:

- In the Ethereum Wallet, click on Contracts on the top right of the screen
- Click Watch Token
- Enter the Token Contract Address `0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413`
- Enter the Token name `The DAO`
- Enter the Token symbol: `Ð`
- Enter Decimal Places: `16`
- Click OK
- You should now have a `The DAO` custom token on your Ethereum Wallet contacts page.

## Interacting with the DAO contract in the Ethereum Wallet

Follow the steps on [daohub.org - Voting and other functions](https://daohub.org/voting.html) to add the DAO token to Ethereum Wallet. In summary these steps are:

- In the Ethereum Wallet, click on Contracts on the top right of the screen
- Click Watch Contract
- Enter the Contract Name `The DAO`
- Enter the Contract Address `0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413`
- On the [daohub.org - Voting and other functions](https://daohub.org/voting.html) page, click on **SHOW JSON-INTERFACE** button. (You can also get the the same JSON-INTERFACE text from [The DAO - Contact Source Code](http://etherscan.io/address/0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413#code)).
- Copy the JSON text in the text box below the button
- Paste the JSON text into the **JSON INTERFACE** text box in the Ethereum Wallet
- Click OK
- You should now have a `The DAO` custom contract on your Ethereum Wallet contracts page.

Comment: Aww yeah #teamwork!

Comment: Yeah! And the next question on meta after [What about adding multiple answers to a same question?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/is-there-a-limit-for-transaction-size/1110#1110) is "What about adding two part answers to the same question?" :-)

Comment: JSON link is dead. https://daowiki.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DAO/How+to+add+and+watch+the+DAO+contract

Comment: JSON link site is back up. I've added alternative link just in case.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot move tokens or vote on proposals until the creation period ends on May 28th. At that point you will be able to send and vote from both MyEtherWallet or Mist. Mist will give you access to everything found in the JSON interface / ABI (splitting, etc etc.) while MyEtherWallet will most likely just provide you with a Send & Vote interface.

If you want to access your tokens in Mist, you need to import the account you made on MyEtherWallet into Mist. You can do so by importing the raw, unencrypted private key via geth or by moving the encrypted keystore file into the same spot Mist keeps them.

Both of these items are described on the [help page, #10](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#help):

#### How do I import a wallet created with MyEtherWallet into geth / Ethereum Wallet / Mist?

**Using your unencrypted private key...**

1. If you do not already have your unencrypted private key, navigate to the "View Wallet Details" tab.
2. Select your wallet file -or- enter/paste your private key to unlock your wallet.
3. Copy Your Private Key (unencrypted).

**If you are on a Mac:**

1. Open Text Edit and paste this private key.
2. Go to the menu bar and click "Format" -> "Make Plain Text".
3. Save this file to your `desktop` as `nothing_special_delete_me.txt`. Make sure it says "UTF-8" and "If no extension is provided use .txt" in the save dialog.
4. Open terminal and run the following command: `geth account import ~/Desktop/nothing_special_delete_me.txt`
5. This will prompt you to make a new password. This is the password you will use in geth / Ethereum Wallet / Mist whenever you send a transaction, so don't forget it.
6. Delete the nothing_special_delete_me.txt from your desktop.
7. The next time you open the Ethereum Wallet application, your account will be listed under "Accounts".

**If you are on a PC:**

1. Open Notepad & paste the private key into notepad.
2. Save the file as nothing_special_delete_me.txt at C:\
3. Run the command, `geth account import C:\nothing_special_delete_me.txt`
4. This will prompt you to make a new password. This is the password you will use in geth / Ethereum Wallet / Mist whenever you send a transaction, so don't forget it.
5. After successful import, delete the file at C:\nothing_special_delete_me.txt
6. The next time you open the Ethereum Wallet application, your account will be listed under "Accounts".

#### Using an Geth/Mist Keystore JSON file from MyEtherWallet v2+....

1. Go to the View Wallet Info Tab.**
2. Unlock your wallet using your ENCRYPTED private key or JSON file.
3. On the right hand side, look for `Download JSON file - Geth/Mist Format (encrypted)`. Press the DOWNLOAD button below that. You now have your keystore file.
4. Open the Ethereum Wallet application.
5. In the menu bar, go "Accounts" -> "Backup" -> "Accounts"
6. This will open your keystore folder. Copy the file you just downloaded (`UTC--2016-04-14........`) into that keystore folder.
7. Your account should show up immediately under "Accounts."