# Gas, gas price, gas cost

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, gas-price, gas-estimate

I have read in the documentation that the `miners set the gas cost`. Does this means that gas cost varies from miner to miner? If not, how it is determined?

Moreover, when a contract is referred in geth we write:

> var token = tokenContract.new(
> supply,
> {
> from:web3.eth.accounts[0],
> data:tokenCompiled.token.code,
> `gas: 1000000`
> }..........

What `gas` is this? Is it the gas cost set by the client? Or the max gas to be used for the transaction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I know how much gas to use when calling a contract?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-do-i-know-how-much-gas-to-use-when-calling-a-contract)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the transaction object `{ from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data:tokenCompiled.token.code, gas: 1000000 }` the `gas` property is indeed the maximum to be used for the transaction.

The transaction object can also have a `gasPrice` property.  Miners determine what `gasPrice` they are willing to accept.  If the `gasPrice` is too small, the miner will ignore the transaction.  Geth is configured so that it should provide a price that most miners will accept, but if you want your transaction to be potentially be processed faster by a miner, you can specify your own `gasPrice`.

Now [gas cost](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/799/how-much-does-it-cost-to-use-a-contract) equals the gas used by the transaction multiplied by `gasPrice`.

Comment: How `gas price` is determined? Each miner can specify his own cost, how geth determines the `market gas price`? And what if user is willing to pay higher `gas price` than the miner is expecting: is the client charged his price or the miner's? And yes the link you have given partially solved my problem, thanks.

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3943/how-does-gas-price-oracle-work and also look at `geth help` miner options.

Comment: `gasPrice` is what YOU are willing to pay. The miners choose which transactions to mine based on gas price (obviously, the higher the gas price, the faster the transaction is mined)