# Is there a 'default' gas price and does it change when price of ether relative to fiat rises?

Tags: gas, gas-price

I understand how gas pricing works, so that is not my question.

My question is, as the price of ether relative to fiat (US $) rises, does the 'default' gas price lower (if there is such a thing as the default gas price)?

In other words, three months ago, when ether was priced at $7.50 US$ and a transaction cost X gas (which would translate to Y dollars), would that same transaction cost twice as much today (if ether is at $15.00 US).

I understand that I could send less gas, but that is not the same thing as the default sent gas lowering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a default gas price in the clients.  For Geth, its gas price oracle (Gpo) has nothing to do with fiat.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/utils/flags.go is Geth's code for the default gas price:

```
GpoMinGasPriceFlag = BigFlag{
    Name:  "gpomin",
    Usage: "Minimum suggested gas price",
    Value: big.NewInt(20 * params.Shannon),
}
```

The Gpo code is at:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/gasprice/gasprice.go

In short, Geth's Gpo looks at how full previous blocks have been, to determine the direction of the gas price (see [How does "Gas Price Oracle" work?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3943/how-does-gas-price-oracle-work)).  If blocks are full, the Gpo will adjust the gas price upwards even if ETH has increased in fiat terms.

Comment: That sounds bad to me. I know we're supposed to live in this "fiat is irrelevant" world, but no-one actually does. But my guess is that people will figure this out and start sending non-default (i.e. lower) gas as the price of ether rises relative to fiat. Does that make sense?

Comment: Does parity have the same sort of default?